# How to constrain parameters of a pure function?

Tags: functions, pure-function

Consider the following definition of `splitList`:

```
elem[list_List, i_Integer] := list[[i]]
splitList[list_, size_Integer] := Table[elem[list, i], {i, size}]
```

Example use is like `splitList[f[x], 3]` to get a list of 3 symbolic expressions, which would expand to `f[x][[1]]`, `f[x][[2]]` and `f[x][[3]]` when `x` attains such a value as to make `f[x]` a true `List`. I can't use literal `list[[i]]`, since `f[x]` is not a list initially, so I'd get `Part::partd` error.

Here `elem` is a function used only once, so it'd be good to avoid even naming it. Naturally, I thought I'd use a pure function for this. But then I come across a problem: my naïve approach doesn't work: the following code

```
splitList[list_, size_Integer] := Table[Function[{x_List,i_Integer},list[[i]] ], {i, size}]
```

emits an error message:

> Function::flpar: Parameter specification {x_List,i_Integer} in Function[{x_List,i_Integer},f[x][[i]]] should be a symbol or a list of symbols.

So, apparently, I can't use patterns in `Function`. How can I constrain parameters of a pure function then?

Comment: You will have a better chance of getting an answer if you explain why you want to constrain the variable types, and what semantics (kinds of actions) you expect when the types don't match (e.g. return the call unevaluated, return `$Failed` or `Failure` object, throw an exception, abort the surrounding `Table` call or loop, etc).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin well, I thought I explained it in the paragraph right after the first snippet: I need to avoid `Part::partd` errors on `list[[1]]` and siblings, and if the types don't match, the behavior should be to leave the expression unevaluated. Basically, I need the functionality of the first snippet, but without naming the `elem` function.

Comment: Well, the "nameless" nature of pure functions is only useful not just when you need to use it only once, but when you need to use it once *within the same evaluation*. In your case, the `elem` function carries certain semantics for what heppens in between evaluations: whenever `list` is not a list, it preserves the call unevaluated. So it is used in more than one evaluation, separated by some time interval (the second one is when `list` actually becomes a list, thus allowing it to evaluate). So this strategy of replacing with `Function` does not seem applicable: `Function` always evaluates.

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving the problem of cluttering the global namespace is to use `Module` with a *locally*-named function, like here:

```
splitList[list_, size_Integer] := 
 Module[{elem},
  elem[data_List, i_Integer] := data[[i]];
  Table[elem[list, i], {i, size}]
 ]
```

This way, although we still give our helper function a name, it's no longer in the global namespace (it's instead automatically suffixed with something like `$2034` with ever-increasing number), so we can reuse the name `elem` however we like without interfering with `splitList`. So, it's basically like a pure function, but with a hidden name.

Comment: Keep in mind that these local symbols will not be garbage-collected and will be accumulating and cluttering the global namespace.And yes, they *still live in global namespace*, making them local to the `Module` does not change that.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following code?

Input:

```
Clear[splitList, elem, f]
splitList[list_, size_] := Quiet[Take[list, size]]
test = splitList[f[x], 10]
f[x] = Range[10];
test
```

Output:

```
Take[f[x], 10]
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

Variable `test` is set the value `Take[f[x], 10]` and keeps unevaluated until `f[x]` is set to be some list.